# Get Release Notes from Electron autoUpdater

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using Electron autoUpdater to update my app, with a private Github repo being the source.
It updates the app fine, but I cannot seem to get my release notes. Are these the description that can be typed in Github after publishing the release? If thats not the case how do I include release notes in new releases?

I have tried getting release notes from:

```js
//info.releaseNotes
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => 
//notes
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info, notes) => 
//info.releaseNotes
autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => 
//notes
autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info, notes) =>
```

All of these log as undefined.

Edit:

Electron builder does not provide the [Github body](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2890) so how do I add release notes?

Comment: Since you have tagged electron-builder assume you're using electron-builder, and it's not supporting gh body for release notes: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2890.

Comment: @OJKwon How do I add release notes then?

Comment: 1. use different auto updater server than gh, manually provide json payload for release note. 2. wait until upstream electron-builder fixes this issue. Also note release-note is not available on Windows anyway, so regardless of fixing this issue you still not able to have release note via autoupdater event handler.

Comment: (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater#event-update-downloaded: `On Windows only releaseName is available.`)

Comment: @OJKWon I do not know why it says that. I was able to get it working on windows. Seems that it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Github body cannot be gotten as of now, so release notes will need to be added directly from the application.

Add release-notes.md to resources folder, and write notes there.

In electron file,

```js
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  //Get release notes 
  info.releaseNotes
```

This works in windows for me.

Comment: what does info returns?